# Showing UIPickerview selected value

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` which displays the array of items. When i select an item, it can be passed to all my view controller. Now my problem is after moving to different `view controllers` and returned back to the `UIPIckerView` it shows the first array item and not the item which i selected. How can i view the selected item?

```
//in viewDidLoad()
itemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"5", @"10", @"20", @"30", @"50",@"100", nil];

// if i select 20 and moved to other pages of my controllers and 
// return to the UIPickerView i can see the 5 as selected not the 20
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show, how you pass data between view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it in different ways

1. Use pass by value or reference in different VCs
2. Store the selected value in some other place which is persistant throughout the runtime and use it

Like

- NSUserdefaults,
- Inside a singleton instance[bad idea,memory retained all time but
  still an option]
- SQLite DB [ok ok,still hard in this case alone]
- coredata [ sofisticated in this purpose]
- In a file [write and read from file operations]

Answer (score 2):

Hi use NSUserDefaults for holding the current selected value using ,

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:albumCount] forKey:@"AlbumCount"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

for retrieving sake ,

```
albumCount = [defaults integerForKey:@"AlbumCount"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the selected value somewhere, either as a property on a view controller or model, or in a central location like `NSUserDefaults`.

Then, when you return to that view controller with the `UIPickerView` you can use 
`- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated` to set the value.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve, and how you're approaching opening a further view it may be as simple as declaring `@property int currentIndex`, setting `currentIndex = indexForSelectedItem` and then in your `viewWillAppear` using it to alert your view what the last selected was.